# Are we able to pull user profile data (beyond basic fields) from Linkedin to our portal application via Linkedin Connection API

Tags: linkedin-api

We are developing a portal application. One of the features for the portal is for users to sign in via SSO Linkedin and to also seek their permission/ consent for them to share Linkedin data to the portal under their profile (beyond basic data such as profile picture, name and email). As part of developing the integration. Is Linkedin be able to support this?

We hit a roadblock to obtain beyond basic data and not sure which API to use.